# Space and Environment.newline (\n) are not coming when i read mails by using c# of gmail which are comes form yahoo mail

Tags: c#, console-application, pop3

I'm reading my gmail inbox by using "open.pop" nuget package. it is working fine and fetching the details in same format in which mail have in my inbox but in case of Yahoo, Space and Environment.newline (\n) are not coming.
i have sent an email to my gmail account

```
add contact
mark
paul
paul@maxvell.com
mind matrix
6756473443
```

but i got this text like

```
add contactmarkpaulpaul@maxvell.commind matrix6756473443
```

space and new line identifiers are missing. this problem is only for those mails which are comes from Yahoo.

Comment: if it's being read in `html` you'll need to use `html` markup as a quick cheat instead of newline use `<br>`

Comment: Did you put someone's email and phone number on a public forum?

Comment: @Amy, no, its dummy data

Comment: Try using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) to see if you still get the same problem, and, if so, you can check the [protocol log](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#q-how-can-i-get-a-protocol-log-for-imap-pop3-or-smtp-to-see-what-is-going-wrong) to see if the message is broken like that on the server.